# How to convert Xpath to CSS

Tags: css, xpath, css-selectors, html-parsing, jsoup

My xpath is: `/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]`

I need to get an CSS to use it in jsoup selector.

I found a comparison between xpath and css: [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/), and it's said in their example (`Second <E> element anywhere on page`) that I can't do it. Xpath `xpath=(//E)[2]` CSS `N\A`.

Maybe I can't find what I'm looking for. Any ideas?

Here's the html I'm trying to parse (I need to get values: `1` and `3`):

```
<div class=tablecont>
    <table width=100%>
        <tr>
            <td class=header align=center>Panel Color</td>
            <td class=header align=center>Locked</td>
            <td class=header align=center>Unqualified</td>
            <td class=header align=center>Qualified</td>
            <td class=header align=center>Finished</td>
            <td class=header align=center>TOTAL</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align=center>
                <div class=packagecode>ONE</div>
                <div>
                <div class=packagecolor style=background-color:#FC0;></div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td align=center>0</td>
            <td align=center>0</td>
            <td align=center>1</td>
            <td align=center>12</td>
            <td align=center class=rowhead>53</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align=center>
                <div class=packagecode>two</div>
                <div>
                    <div class=packagecolor style=background-color:#C3F;></div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td align=center>0</td>
            <td align=center>0</td>
            <td align=center>3</td>
            <td align=center>42</td>
            <td align=center class=rowhead>26</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: But are you looking for the second element anywhere on the page, or the second child of its parent? If it's the former, it can't be done with CSS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While an expression like `(//E)[2]` can't be represented with a CSS selector, an expression like `E[2]` can be emulated using the `:nth-of-type()` pseudo-class:

```
html > body > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(2) > td:nth-of-type(4)
```

Answer (score 10):

Works good for me.

```
//Author: Oleksandr Knyga
function xPathToCss(xpath) {
    return xpath
        .replace(/\[(\d+?)\]/g, function(s,m1){ return '['+(m1-1)+']'; })
        .replace(/\/{2}/g, '')
        .replace(/\/+/g, ' > ')
        .replace(/@/g, '')
        .replace(/\[(\d+)\]/g, ':eq($1)')
        .replace(/^\s+/, '');
}
```

Comment: This translates starting `/` to starting `>` for css, which is wrong.

Comment: Worked ok for me! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/YZu8D/

```
.tablecont tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(4) {background-color: yellow; }
.tablecont tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(4) {background-color: yellow; }
```

Answer (score -1):

One should learn how to write css selectors, but a for a quick fix, try: [cssify](http://cssify.appspot.com/)

For example, I put in your xpath and it spit out: `html > body > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(2) > td:nth-of-type(4)`

Try it out.

Comment: Something like that? @SurajRao