# Generating CSS Selector in Firefox

Tags: c#, css-selectors

Well i used to use htmlagilitypack as well as xPath to scrap some info from websites but i have read that css selectors are much faster so i searched for good engine for css and i found CsQuery; However, i am still confused as i don't know how to get the css path of an element.

In xPath i have used a firefox plugin called xPath checker that returned a fine xPaths like this

```
id('yt-masthead-signin')/button
```

But i can't find an equivalent one for CSS. So if someone helped my i will really appreciate it because i don't find and answer on google for my question specifically.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731332/how-to-convert-xpath-to-css) question

Comment: not a Duplicate i never posted this before...

Comment: also i don't want to convert xPath to css i want a direct plugin or something that can generat an css selector for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/?src=dp-dl-dependencies) + [Firepath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/)

Click the selecting button to select something on the page, then it can generate either xpath or css selector. However, you need some changes to make the generated ones more efficient.

[image: get css selectors using firepath]

Comment: So is there a better way that allows me to get reliable css path without having to edit it as i don't have knowledge about css ?

Comment: The smelly selectors generated by Firepath will always be valid as long as the page doesn't change. If the page changes, even the best selectors may still fail. Also, auto-generated css selectors are more reliable then auto-generated xpath by xPath checker. I really recommend you learn both xpath and css selector, e.g. [article here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/)

Comment: So the best way for auto generated css selector is FirePath. anyway thank you very much for your valuable help and i have marked your answer as the best.

Comment: No worries. Here's an answer worth reading, which also applies to css selector. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4173779/1177636