# XPath to locate a link within a table

Tags: xpath

I have a table as follows:

```
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="client in clients">
<td class="text-left ng-binding">Apu Nahasapeemapetilon</td>
<td class="text-left ng-binding">AN</td>
<td class="text-left">
<span class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="group in client.SecurityGroups">
<a class="label label-info ng-binding" href="#/SecurityGroup/MemberClients/a1cbf118-2c40-4ae7-a9f8-136bec945849/Assistants"> Assistants </a>
<span class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="group in client.SecurityGroups">
<a class="label label-info ng-binding" href="#/SecurityGroup/MemberClients/e4bd1580-3997-4f3d-a975-189e1fdccb4c/Managers"> Managers </a>
```

I am trying to locate on a link in the third cell.  There can be muliple links in this cell.  Ideally I want to identify the row by locating on cells 1 or 2.

So the idea given the table data above is:  Find row with client code AN (in cell 2), then find the link 'Assistants' on that row (in cell 3).

I have a similar table on my project and the following XPpath will do what im aiming for on that table:

```
//tr[.//td='AN'] // a[.='Managers']
```

but it doesnt seem to work on the table above...

If I do:

```
//tr[.//td='AN'] // a
```

It will highlight all the links in the cell (i.e links ending Assistants and Managers), for the row containg 'AN', but I just cant seem to get it to locate on an individual link.

Comment: Your XPath is nearly correct, but in the HTML there are spaces around `Managers` and `Assistants`. You could use `//tr[.//td='AN'] // a[.=' Managers ']` (note the extra spaces) or possibly `//tr[.//td='AN'] // a[contains(., 'Managers')]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following xpath

```
//tr/td[.='AN']/following-sibling::td[1]//a[contains(@href, 'Assistants')]
```

the xpath looks for a `tr` with a child `td` having a value of 'AN'. Then looks at the first following-sibling `td` then looks for a descendant `a` which has an `href` value that contains 'Assistants'

Comment: Thanks - needed to add an additional '/' at the begiining of the XPath , but otherwise it works.  I'm quite new to Xpath, would you mind explaining how that query works?

Comment: Or even if there is a CSS equivalent?

Comment: Read this for a CSS alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731332/how-to-convert-xpath-to-css