# Convert xpath into cssSelector

Tags: css, dom, xpath, css-selectors, domxpath

I am trying to convert xpath

```
//*[@id='formStartQuote']//div[@class='popular-countries']//ul[1]/li[1]
```

into cssSelector.

I tried all possible ways say

```
#formStartQuote > div.popular-countries ul:nth-of-type(1) > li:nth-of-type(1)
#formStartQuote div.popular-countries ul:nth-of-type(1) > li:nth-of-type(1)
#formStartQuote > div.popular-countries > ul:nth-of-type(1) > li:nth-of-type(1)
```

Nothing worked for me.

Do anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: Try `#formStartQuote div.popular-countries ul > li`

Comment: Provide some example html code to test the solution against

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Xpath to CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731332/how-to-convert-xpath-to-css)